# Ought to have been (adjective/noun)

Tags: meaning, sentence

Could you explain what this sentence means?

- *Well, for one thing, they both ought to have been fatal and weren't,

  although that was pure luck*.

Comment: Consider, hypothetically, a baby born with two potentially fatal conditions, yet the child survives. See answer below for "for one thing."

Comment: It's a mistake. The writer wrote _they both ought to have been fatal_ for _they both ought to have died_, which is just a vivid way of expressing it. But then, having used an adjective (and the wrong one at that -- accidents are fatal, not people),  they were stuck used _weren't_ (instead of _didn't_) in the next clause, and then leaving off the rest by conjunction reduction, even though you can't say *_they both weren't fatal_ idiomatically. As usual, trying to cram too much information into the minimum of words with a maximum of deletions makes for confusing reading.

Comment: The sentence may refer to two separate incidents that ought to have been fatal for one person or one group. We need to have more context here. If I read this correctly, I think the OP's question goes to _ought to_.  Here _ought to_ would mean something like "The incidents would have been fatal under normal circumstances, but by sheer luck, something extraordinary happened to prevent that." For example, a man's plane caught fire, he was ejected without a working parachute, and he just happened, by sheer luck, to land in a hammock.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for all the replies:)

Answer (score 1):

Well,for one thing,they both ought to have been fatal and weren't, although that was pure luck

"For one thing" is a way of saying, "I will list or enumerate the important topics here:"
It makes a special point of the first topic at hand. "It is important to note that this might have been fatal."

"They both ought to have been" means that normally both of *them* would have had a certain experience or event. " Whether "They" is two people or two doses of medicine is not clear. "We would normally have expected a fatal result." The actual fortunate outcome was a lucky one.